# MVC - How to update Model in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

A newbie in MVC here trying to update the Model in the Razor view in MVC as I have to apply runtime filters on the displaying list using @Html.DisplayForModel():

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.tblMember>
@{
     Model = Model.Take(5); // or any updation in model 
}
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

But it's giving following error:

> "Model cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Can you please help me with what is the way to update the model runtime in the view which reflects automatically in DisplayForModel()?

Comment: Why not do that in the action method and send the correct data to the view ?. If you absolutely want to do it in view, assign it to another variable and use it. `var memberList = Model.Take(5);` Now, you probably need to replace `DisplayForModel` with other helpers to render the values.

Comment: That is what the "C" in MVC is for.

Comment: ideally you'd do this in the controller and just pass the already-filtered list to the View. Any particular reason you chose not to do that? Is there some reason that won't work?

Comment: @ADyson, I have to apply onpage filters according to user selection on the rendered list. If for every user selection on page I post the page to controller then the page will get refreshed right? Is there any another way to do it?

Comment: yes - do an ajax request, or use JavaScript to do the filtering instead of Razor code (of course you'd have to download all of your data onto the page first for that to work).

Comment: @ADyson I don't want to use javascript or jQuery

Comment: In that case you have to post back to the server and do the work there. But in a modern web application most users will think that's pretty slow and tedious. Why won't you use JavaScript? That's the only way you can do any data processing in the browser side. And it's what most web applications do these days

Comment: P.s. you asked this question almost 9 months ago. Please tell me you're not still stuck on the same problem??